# C# WMI remote process execution

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, wmi

I am trying to run a command which invokes a batch file on Win 2008 box. (The commands runs successfully when I log in to Win 2008 and click).

But when I call this batch file via WMI using same user credentials the batch does not execute.

My code to connect is:

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
connOptions.Username = UserName;
connOptions.Password = Password;

ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(
    String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", ComputerName), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();

ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(
    manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

inParams["CommandLine"] = command;
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
Object returnValue = outParams["ReturnValue"];
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Which is the ReturnValue value after of the execution of this code?

Comment: Return value is 0.. Which I suppose is returned when there is no error.

Comment: Then the command was executed, but is not visible to you. because the create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.

Comment: The command executes DD exe for creating system image.. So in that case DD.exe should show up in Task Manager.. It does not show up there :(

Comment: the process dd.exe is not shown in the task manager?

Comment: No it does not.. that is the issue

Comment: The account which you are using has the Execute Method and Remote Enable permissions for the `root\cimv2` namespace?

Comment: When I executed another batch file which has a different command using DD.exe it executes fine with same user account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify explicit credentials when instantiating a command on a remote computer over WMI. WMI enhances security, but in so doing actually reduces security since explicit credential passes them in the clear, unlike a token.

Answer (score 0):

If ROOT\CIMV2 is set as the default namespace for scripting on your server then you should just need the following:

```
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(
    String.Format(@"\\{0}", ComputerName), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();
```